# Prestashop 1.6 want to show manufacturer name on category and sub category page in description

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

My PrestaShop version is 1.6.1.24

I want to show category product manufacturer name no logo just name on category page in description

Expert need your help how can I show this result on category page description?

````
Example Category

Category name is:  Mouse
Result on Category Page in description is: Apple Mouse, Logitech Mouse```


Example Sub Category

Sub Category name is: USB Mouse
Result on Sub Category Page in description is: Apple USB Mouse, Logitech USB Mouse


Example Product

Product on Sub Category : Mouse 202 (Manufacturer is: Apple)
Product on Sub Category : Mouse 203 (Manufacturer is: Logitech)
````

Comment: You want to modify product-list.tpl template, is not it?